# The 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels_'

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

In my code I am using sklearn kMeans algorithm. When I execute the code I get the error "'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels_'"

```
15     "Get cluster labels"
16     label_pre = kmeans_model.labels
17 
18     "Start plot whit 2d visualisation"

AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels''
```

This is my code

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

 def cluster_and_visualise(datafilename:str, K:int, featureNames:list):
 """ Clustering Visualization function """
 "Read in a dataset from a file called 'datafilename'"
 data = np.genfromtxt(datafilename, delimiter=',')
 data = np.array(data)

 "Run the kmeans algorithm on the data"
 kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=K, random_state=0)
 kmeans_model.fit(data)

 "Get cluster labels"
 label_pre = kmeans_model.labels

 "Start plot whit 2d visualisation"
 x0 = data[label_pre == 0]
 x1 = data[label_pre == 1]
 x2 = data[label_pre == 2]

 "Set figure size"
 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
 plt.scatter(x0[:, 0], x0[:, 1], c="red", marker='o', label='banana')
 plt.scatter(x1[:, 0], x1[:, 1], c="green", marker='*', label='apple')
 plt.scatter(x2[:, 0], x2[:, 1], c="blue", marker='+', label='orange')
 plt.xlabel(featureNames[0])
 plt.ylabel(featureNames[1])
 plt.legend(loc=2)

 "Save figure"
 plt.savefig('myVisualisation.jpg')
 "return fig and axes"
 return plt.figure(), plt.axes'
```

To get keywords cluster. I have tried to resolve this issues. But I don't know where I am lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as currently shared, references a `.labels` attribute of your model, not the `.labels_` attribute specified by [Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

Try changing this line:

```
label_pre = kmeans_model.labels
```

to

```
label_pre = kmeans_model.labels_
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, now the code is running smoothly.